# What is the common verbal association?

Tags: word, visual, lateral-thinking, rebus

｜｜  —  S S S

Your answer should be one word to this problem.

Comment: Please don't edit tags or add irrelevant commentary just to bump your question. If your question is not getting as much attention as you'd like, consider adding a hint or adding a bounty.

Comment: First I immediately thought that the irrelevant commentary was just added, but then realized it might be interesting indeed;)

Comment: I don't see a way to add an S to the original question, while still forming a grammatically correct sentence. Would one also need to exchange "is" for "are" by any chance?

Answer (score 35):

The symbols '｜ — S S' could be a visual representation of the word:

> **BARONESSES**

Since:

> The symbol '|' is known as a **BAR**,
>  the dash-like symbol '—' is how the number **ONE** is represented in Mandarin Chinese (Yī),
>  and then you have two '**ESSES**' at the end.

Comment: For the second symbol I also considered that rot13('BA' vf pbzzbayl ercerfragrq ol n yvar ba n cbjre fjvgpu (juvyr 'BSS' vf ercerfragrq ol n pvepyr); ubjrire, guvf vf abeznyyl n **iregvpny** yvar, zhpu yvxr gur one, engure guna ubevmbagny nf guvf qnfu vf qrcvpgrq, fb V unir qvfpbhagrq vg qryvorengryl.)

Comment: very nice :) (but no)

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I like it, but wouldn't BARONESSES be clued as $\overline{SS}$?

Comment: @JMP Agreed, that's certainly another way - but any clue method is entirely dependent on the OP's stylistic preferences...

Comment: very quietly I would express my wonder why a self-contradictory answer is upvoted so high, I see "**baroneesses**" if I read the words together, maybe I don`t understand something.

Comment: What's self-contradictory about this answer?

Comment: @Stiv Maybe the correct answer will be "just" rot13(ONEBARFF)... OOT: Oh hey, BAR and ONE are reversible rot13 :O

Comment: What is this rot13 thing however? I don`t understand it:) Does it mean something like the solution could be "whatever"?

Comment: @balazs.com rot13 is a way to hide spoilers in comments. It shifts the alphabet by 13 letters, so A becomes N (and vice versa), B-O, C-P etc. Use the rot13.com website to encode and decode with ease :)

Comment: Wow...I can decode these things now! I thought these things are just deliberate nonsense . I see this reversibility too. It`s funny

Comment: *Future readers, note:* The OP changed the content of the puzzle on 31 Oct 2019 to include an extra leading bar and trailing S...

Comment: Yes, thanks. And there was a preceding note, that this change would lead to the same solution but decrease difficulty